# Is it "implant inside" or "implant in"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Implant a chip inside a dog to track it.
>
> Implant a chip in a dog to track it.

I am not sure if "in" sounds ok. To me, it sounds odd and ungrammatical. Is it the case? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they both work. In either case, it might sound better to be more specific about what part of the dog you're implanting the chip in. Like "Implant a chip in(side) a **dog's ear** to track it." I don't think one word is more correct than the other, though.